# Trying to reorder posts by event date

Tags: php, wordpress, events

I'm using "the events calendar" plugin in WP which has a feature to allow event posts to show up as regular posts. I currently have a slider on my homepage that I would like to show featured events on. I was able to get it to show events as a "featured" category, but am having trouble ordering it by event date instead of publish date. This is what I have now.

Here is the original code just calling the specific category posts

```
    <?php query_posts ('category_name=' .$slide.'&posts_per_page='.$bvkPP.'&paged='.$paged ); ?>
```

This is what I changed it to

```
    <?php query_posts( array ('category_name=' .$slide.'&posts_per_page='.$bvkPP.'&paged='.$paged, 'orderby' => 'meta_value','meta_key' =>'_EventStartDate','order' => 'ASC',) ); ?>
```

This affectively ordered it by event date, but has overridden the category and is just calling for all events. Any thoughts on how to get just the specific category to show up?

Thanks!

Comment: I would try http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ if you don't get an answer here.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got it figured out. Here's what I came up with.

```
    <?php query_posts( array( 
    'category_name' => $slide, 
    'posts_per_page' => $bvkPP,
    'paged'=> $paged, 
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key' => '_EventStartDate',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'eventDisplay'=> 'startDate',
    'post_type'=> 'tribe_events' ) ); ?>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

> get all event using your cat id.

```
<?php
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1 );
    $args = array(
                'tax_query' => array(
                                    array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'tribe_events_cat',
                                        'field' => 'id',
                                        'terms' => '17' //17 is cat id
                                    )
                                ),
                                'eventDisplay'=>'startDate',
                                'post_type'=>'tribe_events',
                                'orderby'=>'meta_value',
                                'meta_key'=>'_EventStartDate',
                                'posts_per_page' =>10,
                                'paged' => $paged,
                                'order' => 'ASC',
            );
    query_posts($args); 
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    //your code here for get title/content
    <?php   
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_query();
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there any way to just reorder what's already being pulled in, instead of getting the event category id? I'd like it to just use the regular post category that is already showing but reorder it by the event date.